# how to save my fragment content? how to refresh my fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have 2 fragments which are called from the action bar of an activity. Both are gridviews, the first one displays applications with a dedicated adapter, and the second one displays a file list with another adapter. My problem is that when I launch a file then when I back to my activity I switch from one fragment to another, when I come back to the previous one, its content disappears. And when I rotate tablet I have the some problem, because my Fragment restart so for this I think that removing fragment give the possibility to create a new Fragment up to date. How can I save and reload data in my fragment.

How can I manage to update the content of the first fragment while coming back from the second one ? And how to remove fragment after the rotation in order to recreate the Action with new Fragment? I asked this questions but I don't have any responses. [the code is given below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601578/how-to-refresh-a-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is just strings or integers, you can make use of **shared preferences** to store and retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to your first problem -how to save fragment state**

1. Use **setRetainInstance(true)** in you fragments *onCreate()* *it prevents your fragment from destroying and hence recreating.
2. Add your fragment to back stack
3. declare your adapter globally in fragment and resuse it when you get back.

when, you get back to fragment its *onCreateView()* method will be called directly. hence initialize your adapter in *onCreate()* method and use it in *onCreateView()*.

**Solution to your second problem -how to update fragment content**

For this you can use **interface**. create interface in your second fragment and implement it in your first fragment. prefer this doc for this, 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_activitycommunication